# What is the difference between ArrayList<?>, ArrayList, ArrayList<Object>?

Tags: java, generics

Can someone please explain what the difference between `ArrayList<?>`, `ArrayList` and `ArrayList<Object>` is, and when to use each? Are they all same or does each have some different meaning at the implementation level?

Comment: Time to read about `Java Generics`

Comment: I generally don't put any parameters... its "fake" generic anyway.

Comment: @texasbruce That's really a bad idea.

Comment: @arshajii sometimes you have to. Like a HashMap to be dumped as a JSON, the value may be string, number, or array, etc. You cant specify the generic as HashMap<String, XXX>, or just has to be Object.

Comment: @texasbruce It would be preferable to use `Object`. Bad things can happen when you use raw types.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`ArrayList<Object>` is *specifically* a list of `Object`s whereas `ArrayList<?>` is a list whose concrete type we are unsure of (meaning we can't add anything to the list except `null`). You would use the latter when the list's type is irrelevant, e.g. when the operation you want to perform does not depend on the type of the list. For instance:

```
public static boolean isBigEnough(ArrayList<?> list) {
    return list.size() > 42;
}
```

This is all covered in the [generics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) (see the [wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html) section).

Finally, `ArrayList` with no type parameter is the [raw type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html): the only reason it's even allowed is for backwards compatibility with Java versions under 5, and you should refrain from using it whenever possible.

Comment: this is a new perspective :)

Comment: Very nice. I was using ArrayList in some test projects (as I saw it used in a few tutorials.)  The takeaway is, Always use <Object> when you can

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList<?>` means "an `ArrayList` instance containing a type which is to be determined"

`ArrayList` is the class of an `ArrayList`

An `ArrayList<Object>` means an instance of `ArrayList` containing `Object` types.

This looks like it could be a good write-up on this (and more): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Comment: I guess the OP is asking that since in JAVA everything extends from Object, what does it mean to have "a type which is to be determined"? Because the list does not accept primitives