# Having trouble using Arraylist.get method and it's showing "Incompatible operand types Object and int"

Tags: java, arraylist, integer

I was trying to take an unknown number of integers from the user (until the user enters 0), and count the number of occurrences of each of the integers entered. I figured, to count after I'm done taking the integers, I'd have to store them in an array. And I did some research and realized that the only way to create an Array with an unspecified length, ArrayList is the only way. But my this part of the code is showing error:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class IntegersOccurence {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the integers between 1 and 100: ");
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        System.out.println(list.get(0));
        //eclipse is showing an error in the line right below
        while (list.get(list.size() - 1) != 0) {
            list.add(input.nextInt());
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513308/what-is-the-difference-between-arraylist-arraylist-arraylistobject) as it can answer your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should better use this code:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class IntegersOccurence {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the integers between 1 and 100: ");
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(input.nextInt());
        System.out.println(list.get(0));
        //eclipse is showing an error in the line right below
        while (list.get(list.size() - 1) != 0) {
            list.add(input.nextInt());
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `raw type` so type of the list is `Object` which cannot be compared to `int` (`0`) so use

```
 ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

[**Read** , What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

---

[As mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47363284/having-trouble-using-arraylist-get-method-and-its-showing-incompatible-operand#comment81679830_47363440) : you are adding no element in `list`  and invoking `get` will cause a crash because

[From docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get-int-)

> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 ||
>   `index >= size()`

here `index>=size()` is true (list size is 0,no element) so hence exception

Answer (score 0):

Change below line:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
```

To:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

By default the type of your list is Object, by defining the datatype we avoid runtime type errors and the check is being done in compile time.

Comment: Thanks! That helped remove the error! But it's still showing an "Exception in thread "main""

public static void main(String[] args) {   
  Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);  
  
  System.out.print("Enter the integers between 1 and 100: "); <br/>
  
  ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(); <br/>
  boolean val = true;<br/>
  while (val == true ) {<br/>
   
   if (list.get(list.size() - 1) == 0) {<br/>
    val = false;<br/>
   }<br/>
   else {<br/>
    list.add(input.nextInt());<br/>
   }<br/>
  }<br/>
   
 }<br/>

}

Comment: what's the exception?

Comment: Enter the integers between 1 and 100:   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1  
 at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(Unknown Source)  
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)  
 at IntegersOccurence.main(IntegersOccurence.java:16)

Comment: @FahimSiddiqui exception is because there is no data in your list and `list.get(`  you get index  out of exception

Comment: This is what it's showing after I run the code

Comment: Oh thanks a lot. Fixed it.

Comment: Your "to" line uses a raw type. It should be `ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();`